# How to get dictionary from user with a key and an array of values as a 2D list in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

The input will be in the 4*4 format and the first number in the dictionary would be the key and the corresponding numbers would be in the form of a list.

**For Example:**
In a matrix like :

1 2 4 5

3 4 3 6

.......the numbers 1 and 3 are the keys and the remaining numbers in the first row are in the form of a list.

Can somebody help me out?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your input? A text file, user input from the console? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I haven't tried anything so far, as I don't know how to get user input for dictionary in Python with keys and values separated. I need to get a 4*4 matrix where the first index value in each row is the key and the numbers next to it are the values(to be taken as list)

Comment: The point is: what data structure is your 4*4 matrix. `matrix` is not a Python type.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I just need a 2-dimensional list.....with m rows and n columns. I didn't know that, there is no matrix in Python. I meant a 2D list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that I understand correctly, the following should do:

```
m = [[1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 3, 6]]
d = {k: v for k, *v in m}
# {1: [2, 4, 5], 3: [4, 3, 6]}
```

Or for the reverse direction:

```
[[k, *v] for k, v in d.items()]
# [[1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 3, 6]]
```